# How to avoid duplicates in creating view with Left Join if a joining column in one table can have duplicates?

Tags: sql, view, left-join

I need to create a view from 2 tables.  They are linked by one column, but in one table this column is a primary key, in another table this column can have duplicates.   The resulting view should not have duplicates for this column.  If a row in the 2nd table meets CASE condition then the result in the view should be 'Y' regardless on other rows for the same key.

Please, see the scrip and the join results.  **The 1st row in the results is incorrect, it should be eliminated**

```
Create table A1Table(
    a Integer not null
);

Create table A2Table(
    a Integer,
    b Integer
);

insert into A1Table values (1);
insert into A1Table values (2);
insert into A1Table values (3);
insert into A2Table values (1, 1);
insert into A2Table values (1, 100);

CREATE VIEW A12 AS select a1.a,
CASE
    WHEN a2.b=100 AND a2.b is not NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS report
FROM A1Table a1
Left JOIN A2Table a2 ON a2.a = a1.a;
```

-->

```
   a | report
  ---+--------
 **1 | N** -> *should be eliminated*
   1 | Y
   2 | N
   3 | N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the condition on `a2.b` in the JOIN condition.

```
SELECT a1.a,
       IF(a2.b IS NOT NULL, "Y", "N") report
FROM A1Table a1
LEFT JOIN A2Table a2 ON a1.a = a2.a AND a2.b = 100
```

I'm assuming that the combination `a, b` should be unique in `A2Table`. If you can have duplicate combinations, then you need to use a subquery with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT a1.a,
       IF(a2.b IS NOT NULL, "Y", "N") report
FROM A1Table a1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a, b
           FROM A2Table
           WHERE b = 100) a2 ON a1.a = a2.a
```

Comment: Yes, LEFT JOIN A2Table a2 ON a1.a = a2.a AND a2.b = 100 works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since `Y` is larger than `N`, you could:

```
select  a
,       max(report) as NoDuplicateReport
from    (
        select  a1.a
        ,       CASE
                WHEN a2.b=100 AND a2.b is not NULL THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
                END AS report
        FROM    A1Table a1
        LEFT JOIN 
                A2Table a2 
        ON      a2.a = a1.a
        ) SubQueryAlias
group by
        a
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how this will work.  In reality this view has very many columns from different tables, I just showed what gives the problem